# How to reference a class in another project?

Tags: sbt, scaladoc

I have a multi-project SBT configuration. I have a class `my.AClass` in  `project1`. What should I add to configuration to make scaladoc as follows

```
/**
 * [[my.AClass]]
 */
class BClass
```

in project2 be successfully compiled by `sbt project2/doc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using https://github.com/sbt/sbt-unidoc ? If not, perhaps it may be the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
  val scalaVer = "2.12"
  val commonSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    autoAPIMappings := true,
    apiURL := Some(url(s"file:${baseDirectory.value.getAbsolutePath}/target/scala-${scalaVer}/api")),
  )
  lazy val a = (project in file("a")).settings(commonSettings)
  lazy val b = (project in file("b")).settings(commonSettings)
```